# Hide and show the tables in html using jquery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning to design a web. My problem is there are two combo box the **Instrument** which compose of ACOUSTIC GUITAR,DRUM and PIANO, and **Level** compose of MAINSTREAM, PRIMARY A , BEGINNER ETC.

If I click the combo box the table named **Create Your Own Schedule** appear but when I click for **EXAMPLE**:the instrument(PIANO) or level(BEGINNER) it will disappear. Every click on the combo box it will show or hide.. What I want to do is that if I click the combo box and choose the instrument PIANO and level BEGGINER that's only the time that the table will appear/ display

PLEASE HELP: below is what I've done

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
            <script>
                function toggle() {
                 if( document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display=='none' ){
                   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'table-row'; // set to table-row instead of an empty string
                 }else{
                   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'none';
                 }
                }
            </script>
            <section id="download-bootstrap">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>1. Create Schedule</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="well well-large">
                <p class="lead">Select Your Instrument and Level</p>
                <div class="controls controls-row">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Instrument</td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" id="colorselector" name="Activity"  onClick="toggle();">
                                <option selected="selected" onClick="toggle();" >-- Select --</option>
                                <option value="1">ACOUSTIC GUITAR</option>
                                <option value="2">DRUM</option>
                                <option value="3">PIANO</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; Level</td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" id="colorselector" name="Activity" onclick="toggle();">
                                <option selected="selected" >-- Select --</option>
                                <option value="4">MAINSTREAM</option>
                                <option value="5">BEGINNER</option>
                                <option value="6">PRIMARY A</option>
                                <option value="7">INTERMEDIATE A</option>
                                <option value="8">INTERMEDIATE B</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <div id="hidethis" style="display: none;">
                <p>Create Your Own Schedule</p>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped responsive-utilities">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>SUNDAY</th>
                            <th>MONDAY</th>
                            <th>TUESDAY</th>
                            <th>WEDNESDAY</th>
                            <th>THURSDAY </th>
                            <th>FRIDAY</th>
                            <th>SATURDAY</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible" style="background-color: #f9f9f9 !important">Reserved</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>8:30-9:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                            <td class="is-visible">Available</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>   
  </html>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO ... please include in your question just the relevant code, just the necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry... I just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a check on change event of both dropdowns call a function, where make a check as below

HTML:

-- Select --
                        ACOUSTIC GUITAR
                        DRUM
                        PIANO

```
                <select class="form-control" id="level" name="level" onchange="toggle();">
                    <option selected="selected" >-- Select --</option>
                    <option value="4">MAINSTREAM</option>
                    <option value="5">BEGINNER</option>
                    <option value="6">PRIMARY A</option>
                    <option value="7">INTERMEDIATE A</option>
                    <option value="8">INTERMEDIATE B</option>
                </select>
```

JS :

```
  function toggle(){
        if(jQuery('#activity').val == 'PIANO' && jQuery('#level').val == 'BEGINNER'){
              jQuery('#idTable').css('display','block')
        }

    }
```

Have used jquery u can include it adding below line in your script in head.

Comment: Have edited my answer , see if it helps. Pls add jquery, have shared the link or else have to write in core javascript.

Comment: This will only show the table if the user specifically selects "PIANO" and "BEGINNER" but not for anything else. Copy-pasting the code repeatedly for the other 89 possible combination is not a good idea. It needs to be more generic.

Comment: guess ,i din't got your question correctly. what are the combinations in which table should appear?? and yes if this is the case it has to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes you need to make in your HTML and JS code. Please see the changes given below. If you make these changes then it will work as expected.

HTML Code -

```
                    <select class="form-control" id="activity" name="activity"  onClick="toggle();">
                        <option selected="selected" onClick="toggle();" >-- Select --</option>
                        <option value="1">ACOUSTIC GUITAR</option>
                        <option value="2">DRUM</option>
                        <option value="3">PIANO</option>
                    </select>


                    <select class="form-control" id="level" name="level" onclick="toggle();">
                        <option selected="selected" >-- Select --</option>
                        <option value="4">MAINSTREAM</option>
                        <option value="5">BEGINNER</option>
                        <option value="6">PRIMARY A</option>
                        <option value="7">INTERMEDIATE A</option>
                        <option value="8">INTERMEDIATE B</option>
                    </select>
```

JS Code -

```
        function toggle() {
         var activity=document.getElementById("activity");
         var level=document.getElementById("level");
             if(activity[activity.selectedIndex].value !="-- Select --" && level[level.selectedIndex].value !="-- Select --"){
                document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'table-row';

             }
             else{

                document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'none';
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every click on either the Instrument or Level combo box calls the `toggle()` function. 
That function is showing/hiding the `hidethis` div on every click.

You also call this function when clicking the `-- Selected --` element in the Instrument menu, which you probably don't want to do.

What you probably want is to show/hide the schedule only when they've selected both an instrument and a level. For that, you'll need more JavaScript and a conditional to check that a selection has been made in both menus.

Ensure both combo boxes have unique IDs and names that you can target using JavaScript (right now they're both identical). Also, the use of inline JS events like "onclick" or "onchange" is generally no longer considered to be best practice. Instead, use the IDs to attach eventListeners to the elements in a separate JS file. That will make your HTML easier to edit/maintain, and your JS more flexible.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42767537/1)

```
<div class="instruments">
     <select class="form-control" id="instrumentSelector" name="activity">
         <!-- Your Instrument Options -->
      </select>
</div>
<div class="levels">    
  <select class="form-control" id="levelSelector" name="level">
         <!-- Your Level Options -->
      </select>
</div>

<div id="hidethis" style="display: none;">
       <!-- Table to show/hide -->
</div>
```

You can either include the following inline in a `<script></script>` block in your HTML (not best practice) or as a separate .js file linked inside your `<head>` tag.

```
 //Global variables aren't great, but they work. Set them to an initial value
var selectedInstrument, selectedLevel = "-- Select --";


//You can use "onchange" here or "addEventListener". 
//This also duplicates code so it isn't ideal, but it will work for your needs.

document.getElementById("instrumentSelector").onchange = function() {
    selectedInstrument = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
    toggleTable();
}

document.getElementById('levelSelector').onchange = function() {
    selectedLevel = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
    toggleTable();
}

 function toggleTable () {
    //Ensure both an instrument and a level have been set
    if (selectedInstrument != "-- Select --" && selectedLevel != "-- Select --")
    {
       document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = "table-row";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = "none";
    }

};
```